# jars for mass email sending

Tags: java, email, jsp

in my webapplications whihc runs on tomcat on widows i want to send email to many different people
for example whenever a new tutials is uploaded on my site an email shold go to all the registed user on my site.
simlarly whenever some other event occors i need to send the email to some selected users whose emailid are picked up from database.
I want a jar which can be used to send such messages.
I wil pass a array of receipienst to it.
are there some free jars available for this ??
jars shold me able to queue the msgs and send to the recipients
let me explain in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)

Comment: i know that i can use javmail.jar and activation.jar
but i need to send bulk emails easy.

Comment: Javamail is quite capable of bulk emails. You'll need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: You can send any number of recipients via email.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [commons email](http://commons.apache.org/email/)

Answer (score 0):

The "queue" ability usually requires a SMTP server which traditionally is provided by your Internet Service Provider.  You then use e.g. JavaMail to generate all those mails you need to send and forward them to the SMTP-server and let it handle all the details.

If you really, really need to run your own SMTP-server, I believe James can do it (http://james.apache.org/) but I would recommend the ISP approach.

Comment: i dont have my own smtp server. i use gmail smtp server to send my mails. so i need to run a thread that picks the msgs form my databse and send to appripraite receiver